# Sorting big tables with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, sorting, html-table, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to sort a table where the header and content are retrieved with `ng-repeat`. When I click on a header item, I want that column to be sorted alphabetically. But I am not sure how I can get this done

This is my html:

```
<div class="pane pane--table1">
  <div class="pane-hScroll">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-repeat="item in header" ng-click="sortColumn()">{{item}}</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
    </table>
    <div class="pane-vScroll">
      <table>
        <tbody>
          <div ng-include="'templates/includes/ajax_spinner.html'"></div>
          <tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in content">
            <td ng-repeat="val in value track by $index">{{val}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you can use ui-grid angular library, it provides plenty of options. http://ui-grid.info/

Answer (score 0):

You could use orderBy filter with property name like below

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyController">
  <div ng-repeat="item in array  | orderBy: !changeFilter ? '-date' : 'name'">
    <div>{{item.name}}</div>
  </div>
  <button ng-click="changeFilter=!changeFilter">
    change
  </button>

</div>
```

Here's JSFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/aiubian/fn44eqkb/